# How do I cancel Node.JS request handling when that request is aborted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, xmlhttprequest, request

What is the proper way to stop the chain of events on a Node server that was set in motion after it received a request, when that request is cancelled?

E.g.

- When you press `[escape]` while a request is done by a browser, the request is aborted.
- When you call `.abort()` on a jQuery `$.ajax()`.
- etc

For just serving some html, this wouldn't be a big deal. The Node server renders some text and nobody listens to the output. Not a big deal.

But when the Node server is actually doing a *lot* of processing for the response, it would be nice to be able to stop and use the resources for something else.

Ideally some kind of trick to `req` itself, so I don't have to change whole batches of code to cancel each promise individually.

Comment: You can use promise libraries with `.cancel` to write the API to get a similar deferred interface - look into Bluebird.

Comment: I use [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference) extensively. Anything similar for `Q`?

Comment: Yes I believe Q does this too - check the API docs, but to be honest I'd switch to the much faster Bluebird if I were you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling cancelled request with Express/Node.js and Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198208/handling-cancelled-request-with-express-node-js-and-angular)