# Handling cancelled request with Express/Node.js and Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, request-cancelling

When a pending HTTP request is cancelled by a client/browser it seems that Node with Express continues to process the request. For intensive requests, the CPU is still being kept busy with unnecessary requests.

Is there a way to ask Node.js/Express to kill/stop these pending requests that are requested to be cancelled?

It becomes particularly useful given that since AngularJS 1.5 HTTP request are easily [cancellable](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) by calling `$cancelRequest()` on `$http`/`$resource` objects.

Such cancellations could occur when exposing an API method providing results for auto-completion or search fields: when typing in the field to be autocompleted or type-aheaded, previous request(s) can be cancelled.

A global `server.timeout` does not solve the problem: 1) it is a priori a global setting for all exposed API methods 2) ongoing processing in the canceled request is not killed.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Injected `req`object is shipped with listeners `.on()`.

Listening to `close` event allows to handle when client close the connection (request cancelled by Angular or, e.g., user closed the querying tab).

Here are 2 simple examples how to use the `close`event to stop request processing.

**Example 1: Cancellable synchronous block**

```js
var clientCancelledRequest = 'clientCancelledRequest';

function cancellableAPIMethodA(req, res, next) {
    var cancelRequest = false;

    req.on('close', function (err){
       cancelRequest = true;
    });

    var superLargeArray = [/* ... */];

    try {
        // Long processing loop
        superLargeArray.forEach(function (item) {
                if (cancelRequest) {
                    throw {type: clientCancelledRequest};
                }
                /* Work on item */
        });

        // Job done before client cancelled the request, send result to client
        res.send(/* results */);
    } catch (e) {
        // Re-throw (or call next(e)) on non-cancellation exception
        if (e.type !== clientCancelledRequest) {
            throw e;
        }
    }

    // Job done before client cancelled the request, send result to client
    res.send(/* results */);
}
```

**Example 2: Cancellable asynchronous block with promises (analog to a reduce)**

```js
function cancellableAPIMethodA(req, res, next) {
    var cancelRequest = false;

    req.on('close', function (err){
       cancelRequest = true;
    });

    var superLargeArray = [/* ... */];

    var promise = Q.when();
    superLargeArray.forEach(function (item) {
            promise = promise.then(function() {
                if (cancelRequest) {
                    throw {type: clientCancelledRequest};
                } 
                /* Work on item */ 
            });
    });

    promise.then(function() {
        // Job done before client cancelled the request, send result to client
        res.send(/* results */);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        // Re-throw (or call next(err)) on non-cancellation exception
        if (err.type !== clientCancelledRequest) {
            throw err;
        }
    })
    .done();
}
```

Comment: You might want to listen for `"aborted"` instead of `"close"`. https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_event_aborted

Comment: `'aborted'` is now deprecated in 17.0; not sure what the right event is, then...

Comment: Docs say check `destroyed` instead of `aborted` - https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestdestroyed

Answer (score 10):

With express, you can try:

```
req.connection.on('close',function(){    
  // code to handle connection abort
  console.log('user cancelled');
});
```

Comment: There's a big difference between connection/socket and request. Listening to connection close could be a (big) mistake (although everything will prbly work properly in tests) - most of browsers keep connection open, although the request itself finished (see "Connection: keep-alive" header or HTTP persistent connection term), so other requests can use the same underlying connection.

Answer (score -5):

You can set a [timeout](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout) for requests on your server:

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
// Set the timeout for a request to 1sec
server.timeout = 1000;
```

Comment: I would like to cancel a request as soon as the client asks to cancel it. Useful with queries for auto-completion.

Comment: I've added some comments in the question about this situation: A global server.timeout does not solve the problem: 1) it is a priori a global setting for all exposed API methods 2) ongoing processing in the canceled request is not killed.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it.